# How to create a regex for alphanumeric, space & apostrophe then ends only in alphanumeric?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a regex based on some constraints, and I've used a couple helpful resources to try & test this. I understand I need an anchor ($) to check the end of the string but I guess I'm misunderstanding where the anchor should be placed.

I know that `/([A-Za-z0-9' ])\w+/` will give me what I want in that it contains alphanumeric+spaces+apostrophe characters, but how do I ensure it only ends in alphanumeric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have there basically says "give me one character that is alphanumeric, an apostrophe or a space, than any number of words". It can also be anywhere, so your string could contain other characters as well. Based on your description, that might not be what you want.

I think you probably want this:

```
/^([A-Z0-9' ]+)(?:[A-Z0-9])$/i
```

This says "give me only alphanumeric, apostrophes or spaces and make sure there is an alphanumeric at the end". I took out the lowercase and just added the `i` (case-insensitive) flag, but you can switch it the other way too.

The `(?:[A-Z0-9])` is a non-matching set that checks to make sure there is an alphanumeric here. Since it is bumped up next to the `$` at the end, it means it must be directly at the end of the string. You also need a `^` at the beginning to ensure that your whole string meets this criteria, not just part of it.

Here is an example:

```js
const pattern = /^([A-Z0-9' ]+)(?:[A-Z0-9])$/i;
['This should work', "This'll also work", "This won't'"].forEach(s => 
  console.log(s, pattern.test(s))
  );
```

Comment: Thanks, I got a better understanding of what's going on & I appreciate it!

Comment: So I've modified it to prevent it from starting with apostrophes as well, based on my testing it works, does this look right: `/^([A-Z0-9 ])([A-Z0-9 ']+)(?:[A-Z0-9])$/i`?

Comment: Yeah, looks like that should do the trick. It says "Give me one alphanumeric or space, then one or more alphanumeric, space or apostrophe, and make sure it ends alphanumeric". Do note that with that pattern, it will require a minimum of 3 characters.